# App se reinicia desde cero y no me deja en el ultimo Activity abierto

Tags: android

Estoy programando una aplicación en **Android Studio**, pero me he encontrado con un problema:

1. Entro a mi Aplicación y me lanza la actividad principal.
2. Presiono un botón que me lanza a una segunda actividad.
3. Presiono el botón Home y después regreso a mi aplicación.

Al realizar esos pasos, cuando vuelve a abrir la aplicación, no se mantiene en la ultima actividad abierta. la Aplicación se reinicia desde cero.

¿Alguien sabe que puedo hacer para mantener el ultimo estado de mi aplicación?, Es decir que no se reinicie desde cero cuando la minimizo.

Comment: Ya verificaste los ciclos de vida de una Actividad en Android ? http://androideity.com/2011/07/06/ciclo-de-vida-de-una-actividad/

Comment: si, ya los revise, pero no se como evitar que se ejecute el metodo que reinicia la app desde 0, como si fuera la primera vez que se abre

Comment: Según lo que comentas al presionar "home" regresas a la actividad principal pero dejas abierta la segunda actividad? El home no es la actividad principal?

Comment: me queda claro que el metodo onRestar(), hace que se inicie desde 0, como  lo evito?

Comment: Gustavo, si estas realizando algo dentro onRestart() sería mejor agregaras tu código para que te ayuden lo desarrolladores.

Comment: Elenasys, la aplicacion abre la actividad principal "A" y al presionar un boton dentro de la actividad "A" me abre una actividad "B", y cuando salgo de la aplicacion y vuelvo a entrar en ella, comienza desde la actividad "A" y no desde la actividad "B"

Comment: onCreate y onClick son los unicos metos que estoy utilizando:

Comment: Tendrias que guardar la instancia de tu activity y volverla a obtener cuando vuelvas creo que se llama savebunlde activity algo asi , tengo un ejemplo si necesitas mas ayuda me puedes contactar

Answer (score 1):

Lo que preguntas es :

> porque no inicia en la última Activity abierta cuando cierras tu
>   aplicación?

Necesariamente tu aplicación tiene una de sus activities configurada para ser el punto de inicio de tu aplicación, lo cual puedes ver dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Mi App">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```